# List Comprehension with Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

At the moment I am trying to figure out how to solve a simple problem using List Comprehension. The point is to make a list and fill it with 1 at the beginning and at the end of the list. The rest elements are filled with 0.

I already tried the following:

```py
desired_length = int(input('Enter the desired length: '))
list_=[0 if x==0 if x==desired_length-1 else x for x in range(desired_length)]
print(list_)
```

**Edit** Fixed the square brackets

And here is the code I am trying to convert:

```py
def test():
    desired_length = int(input('Enter the desired length: '))
    list_ = []
    for i in range(desired_length):
        if i == 0 or i == desired_length - 1:
            list_.append(1)
        else:
            list_.append(0)
    print(list_)
```

Comment: `{0 if x==0 if x==desired_length-1 else x for x in range(desired_length)}` this is a **set comprehension**

Comment: Why don't you use `or` like in your original?

Comment: You wrote a set comprehension instead of a list, `if` instead of `or`, `x` instead of `0`, and `0` instead of `1`. Precision is key in programming.

Comment: Oh , my mistake. I made a typo with brackets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly a dictionary is defined by `{}` and a list by `[]` you are defining a dictionary not a list.

Secondly, this is what you want

```
[1 if (idx==0 or idx == (desired_length-1)) else 0 for idx in range(desired_length)]
```

what you are doing sets 1 at the start and end but 1,2,3 and so on in between

Thirdly, you have the condition set to put 0 at the start and end rather than 1.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed made a mistake. My main intension was to use the list, not set.

Comment: he was using a **set** comprehension not a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 very easy ways of achieving the result you want.

You could use the `in` operator and since `bool` Is a subset of `int` Just cast it to `int`:

```
list_ = [int(i in (0, desired_length - 1)) for i in range(desired_length)]
```

Or just using the star operator to unpack a list of zeros of  `length-2` And put `1`'s at each end, no looping required

```
list_ = [1, *([0]*(desired_length-2)), 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension

```
desired_length = int(input('Enter the desired length: '))
list_ = [(1 if i in [0,desired_length-1] else 0) for i in range(desired_length)]
print(list_)
```

output

```
Enter the desired length: 10
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
desired_length = int(input('Enter the desired length: '))
lst = [1 if idx == 0 or idx == desired_length-1 else 0 for  idx,x in enumerate(range(desired_length))]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do that.
Here is my code:

```py
def test():
    desired_length = int(input('Enter the desired length: '))
    list_ = [0]*desired_length
    list_[0]=1
    list_[-1]=1
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using short-circuit expression here instead of ternary condition (just like [Imtinan Azhar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56951852/11726178))

```py
[int(idx==0 or idx==desired_length - 1) for idx in range(desired_length)]
```